# Deleted boot partition accidentally with gpart

Tags: freebsd, disk

I just typed

```
gpart delete -i 1 ada0
```

when I was supposed to write

```
gpart delete -i 1 ada1
```

and unfortunately typed `reboot` before I noticed my mistake. The disk ada0 had the default GPT layout that the FreeBSD 10.1 installer puts there on default partitioning options.

Obviously, the system won't reboot now, so is there a way to add the partition back? What is the quickest way to restore the machine? I do not wan't to do a full reinstall, because the system has tons of custom changes, which will take a lot of time to redo.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work. Download a FreeBSD installation disk and boot it into single user mode. When done do:

```
gpart show ada0
```

which should print you text describing the disk layout. The result would look like:

```
=>       34  500118125  ada0  GPT  (238G)
         34       1024     1  - free -  (512K)
       1058  490732544     2  freebsd-ufs  (234G)
  490733602    8388608     3  freebsd-swap  (4.0G)
  499122210     995949        - free -  (486M)
```

Now you can backup the GPT for editing by issuing `gpart backup ada0`, which should give something along the lines of (since you deleted partition 1):

```
GPT 128
2    freebsd-ufs      1058 490732544  
3   freebsd-swap 490733602   8388608
```

copy the output to a file and edit it like so (the numbers following freebsd-boot are the numbers for the free space from `gpart show ada0`):

```
GPT 128
1   freebsd-boot        34      1024  
2    freebsd-ufs      1058 490732544  
3   freebsd-swap 490733602   8388608
```

If you've stored the above to a file called `newgpt`, then the following restores the GPT to a condition which should allow booting:

```
gpart restore -F ada0 < newgpt
gpart bootcode -b /boot/pmbr -p /boot/gptboot -i 1 ada0
```

The last command should be redundant, since the boot code should be intact on the disk, but since I don't have a system to break for testing this, I'm putting it there in case.